# How to sort a column alphabetically in excel through python?

Tags: python, excel, sorting

My task was to create a playlist with the title,artist and length and genre but the titles had to be sorted alphabetically
i tried to sort out my song title column but it isnt working at all. Here's my code:

## Songs list

```
songs=open("songs.csv","w")
song_record="song title"+","+"artist"+","+"track length"+","+"genre"
songs.write(str(song_record)+"\n"+"\n")


print("Welcome! Please choose 5 songs per genre")
for i in range (3):
    songtitle=str(input("What is the song called"))
    artists=str(input("Who sung the song ( the main person)"))
    length=str(input("In seconds, how long is the song- 1 min= 60 seconds"))
    genree=str(input("What genre is this song"))
    song_record=songtitle+","+artists+","+length+","+genree
    songs.write(str(song_record)+"\n")
songs.write("\n")
songs.close()

songs=open("songs.csv","a+")
csv1=csv.reader(songs,delimiter=",")
sort=sorted(csv1,key=operator.itemgetter(0))
print(sort)
songs.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using csv.reader, use pandas.read_csv and then use sort_values function to sort the values.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("songs.csv")
df=df.sort_values(['songtitle'], ascending=[True])
```

You can set ascending as False if you wish to.

Comment: it came up with : raise KeyError(key)